# Oracle ADF - programmatically updating ApplicationModule properties

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I want to set the application module configuration property(jbo.ampool.timetolive) value from a managed bean on a button click from the adf page, I have tried with following code but the property value is not getting set.

```
public Object getInfo(String string, Object environment) {
    Hashtable envHashtable = (Hashtable)environment;      
    envHashtable.put(ApplicationModule.PROPERTY_LABEL.equals("jbo.ampool.timetolive"),"7200000");
    return null;
}
```

kindly help me out on this

Comment: Please invest some time, [edit] your question, and improve it so that it is readable and answerable. I suggest following this [checklist by Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I'm not sure why all the downvotes.  I agree it's not a model question, but it's clear enough what he's asking in you know ADF.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that's tricky stuff, but here is what I would try:

In your configurations (bc4j.xcfg file), set the `jbo.ampool.sessioncookiefactoryclass` to point to a class that you will provide (let's call it `MySessionCookieFactory`)

```
<BC4JConfig ...>
   <AppModuleConfigBag ...>
      <AppModuleConfig ...>
         <AM-Pooling jbo.ampool.sessioncookiefactoryclass="mypackage.MySessionCookieFactory"/>
```

That class, `MySessionCookieFactory` must extend `oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieFactory` and override `createSessionCookie` to pass back a custom EnvInfoProvider.

```
public SessionCookie createSessionCookie(String applicationId, String sessionId, ApplicationPool pool,
                                         Properties properties) {
    final SessionCookie cookie = mFactory.createSessionCookie(applicationId, sessionId, pool, properties);
    final EnvInfoProvider provider = new MyEnvInfoProvider();
    cookie.setEnvInfoProvider(provider);
    return cookie;
}
```

`MyEnvInfoProvider` must extend `oracle.jbo.common.ampool.EnvInfoProvider` and override `getInfo()` to pass back and environment that has the value of `jbo.ampool.timetolive` that you want.

So, in `MyEnvInfoProvider`...

```
@Override
public Object getInfo(String infoType,
                       Object configurationEnvironmentObject) {
    // NOTE: Watch logging in this method.  It gets called for *every request* and it can really clutter up a log.
    // Cast the configuration environment passed in to it's correct type.  It's really lame that Oracle's signatures include Object types
    // instead of the correct classes or interfaces.
    final Hashtable<String, String> configurationEnvironmentHashtable =
                                     (Hashtable<String, String>) configurationEnvironmentObject;

//        if (EnvInfoProvider.INFO_TYPE_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT.equals(infoType)) {
        configurationEnvironmentHashtable.put(PropertyConstants.ENV_AMPOOL_TIME_TO_LIVE, (String) MyClass.getTTL());
//        }
    return configurationEnvironmentHashtable;
}
```

So, if you do all that, you'll control `jbo.ampool.timetolive` to be whatever gets returned by `MyClass.getTTL()`.  So, all you need to do is update a variable that `MyClass.getTTL()` and it will get used as `jbo.ampool.timetolive`.

I have done this approach environment settings, but not with `jbo.ampool.timetolive` in particular, so I can't guarantee this will work for you.

Also, why do you need to set this dynamically?  Why not just put 720000 in your `bc4j.xcfg` file and be done with it?